# nodejs net.createServer save scope

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have an application listening on port using net.createServer and socket.io on other port.
net.createServer has many clients connected. After receiving command from browser via socket.io I need to coordinate work of two net.createServer clients. So I send command over first socket to first client and I need to proceed further only when it replays. But how do I save my current scope? Any way to keep "this"?

### UPDATE1:

[Here](http://pastebin.com/UhdUyKDX) is a basic example

Comment: Something to deal with .bind()?

Comment: Can you maybe post some example code?

Comment: you could emit Events and pass the this context to the listener callback as a variable

Comment: OK. I'll add some basic example to have an idea of what's happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to save "this" scope is to use bind(this) on a function definition

```
function(arg){...}.bind(this);
```